# How can I compare values in SQL with special characters?

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I’m keep receiving errors when I go to run dbSendQuery in R Shiny. The value that I am comparing in SQL to a previous selected value has both a hyphen and whitespace (both values do). It keeps giving me an error saying “incorrect syntax near ‘mig ‘. I’m not sure how to get around this problem. Thanks in advance!

Update: it says I can’t post pictures but I will write my code below

```
#con1 is my connection to SQL

#input$first is my label from a select Input


Df1 <- dbSendQuery(con1, glue_sql("SELECT [redacted column Name] FROM [redacted table name] WHERE [redacted column name] = '{input$first}'", .con = con1))
```

Both `input$first` and the second redacted column name have white space and hyphens in their values

Comment: Also, ‘mig ‘ is the entry in SQL

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: I have just added the code above

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, is it possible that you share a sample of the values `input$first` ? It help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes! For example, one possible value could be:    Mig - Car (Each possible value is in the same format, except the word after the dash varies). The format is always “Mig - [any word]”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glue/versions/1.3.1/topics/glue_sql) and RStudio [tutorial](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glue/versions/1.3.1/topics/glue_sql), you should not be quoting the placeholder expression:

```
query <- dbSendQuery(con1, glue_sql("SELECT [redacted column Name] 
                                     FROM [redacted table name] 
                                     WHERE [redacted column name] = {param}",
                                     param  = input$first,
                                    .con = con1)
DF1 <- dbFetch(query, con1)
```

And if `input$first` contains more than one value, adjust SQL to use `IN`:

```sql
WHERE [redacted column name] IN {param*}
```

---

Alternatively, use DBI's parameterization method, `sqlInterpolate`, which should work in most R `DBI` packages (e.g., `RPostgreSQL`, `ROracle`, `RMySQL`, `odbc`):

```
sql <- sqlInterpolate(con, 
  "SELECT [redacted column Name] 
   FROM [redacted table name] 
   WHERE [redacted column name] =  ?param", 
  param = input$first
)

DF1 <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```